# How to use poller trigger in spring integration int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter such that trigger persist in DB

Tags: spring, triggers, integration, quartz-scheduler, poller

I have spring integration inbound adapter which works just fine, below. And I also have setup Quartz in cluster mode (hence persist the trigger/scheduler) in DB. It works fine as well, for Job that extends `org.quartz.Job` class. I am trying to make the the poller in `int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter` to be in cluster mode, so that even when it is deployed in multiple nodes only one of it is running. I got the idea of doing to so for serviceactivator but I am not sure how to do this for scenario like mine where I am using `int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter`. I am using spring 4 and Quartz 2.

---

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter
    id="inboundChannelAdapterIIDDataJpa"
    channel="inboundChannelAdapterOne"
    entity-manager="entityManager"
    jpa-query="select g from House g"
    expect-single-result="false"
    delete-after-poll="false">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50000"> 
        <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
            transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I tried to replace poller ( above ) with

and
then define cron like this;

```
 <bean id="mytrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0/5 * * * ?" />
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="inboundChannelAdapterIIDDataJpa" />
</bean>
```

Here jobDetail ref to the adaptor id. And then have "mytrigger" within scheduler

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mytrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it does not work. I am looking for the solution such that the trigger could be in cluster mode keeping trigger info in quartz table.